# CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED on A100 after server reset

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm running on a server with a A100 GPU. When trying to run tensorflow code after a server reset, tensorflow does not recognize the GPU. Running `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` yields `CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED`:

```
2021-09-09 07:41:42.956917: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-09-09 07:41:43.899014: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: initialization error
2021-09-09 07:41:43.899148: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: f42a3aa12bd1
2021-09-09 07:41:43.899169: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: f42a3aa12bd1
2021-09-09 07:41:43.899890: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:200] libcuda reported version is: 460.32.3
2021-09-09 07:41:43.899955: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:204] kernel reported version is: 460.32.3
2021-09-09 07:41:43.899969: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:310] kernel version seems to match DSO: 460.32.3
```

Running `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  A100-PCIE-40GB      Off  | 00000000:00:06.0 Off |                   On |
| N/A   46C    P0    40W / 250W |      0MiB / 40536MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |              Enabled |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| MIG devices:                                                                |
+------------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| GPU  GI  CI  MIG |         Memory-Usage |        Vol|         Shared        |
|      ID  ID  Dev |           BAR1-Usage | SM     Unc| CE  ENC  DEC  OFA  JPG|
|                  |                      |        ECC|                       |
|==================+======================+===========+=======================|
|  No MIG devices found                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why do I get `CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED`? The server ran perfectly well before the reset, and nvidia-smi is clearly working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems NVIDIA Multi-Instance GPU (MIG) is enabled on your GPU, but you haven't defined any GPU instances. This can be seen from the fact that `nvidia-smi` shows a `MIG devices` table, but it's empty (`No MIG devices found`).

The [MIG documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/mig-user-guide/#running-with-mig) states:

> Without creating GPU instances (and corresponding compute instances),
> CUDA workloads cannot be run on the GPU. In other words, simply
> enabling MIG mode on the GPU is not sufficient. Also note that, the
> created MIG devices are **not persistent across system reboots**. Thus,
> the user or system administrator needs to recreate the desired MIG
> configurations if the GPU or system is reset.

You probably had a MIG configuration defined before the reset, but the server reset removed that configuration. You need to re-configure the GPU instances to get the GPU working again. If you just want a basic configuration, in which you have only one GPU instance that uses all the resources, you can run:

```
sudo nvidia-smi mig -cgi 0 -C
```

If you need a fancier configuration than that, you should consult the documentation.

After configuring the GPU instances, the `nvidia-smi` command should show the `MIG devices` table full. In our case, it should have one entry:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| MIG devices:                                                                |
+------------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| GPU  GI  CI  MIG |         Memory-Usage |        Vol|         Shared        |
|      ID  ID  Dev |           BAR1-Usage | SM     Unc| CE  ENC  DEC  OFA  JPG|
|                  |                      |        ECC|                       |
|==================+======================+===========+=======================|
|  0    0   0   0  |      0MiB / 40536MiB | 98      0 |  7   0    5    1    1 |
|                  |      1MiB / 65536MiB |           |                       |
+------------------+----------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```