# Multiprocessing on multiple function with GPU processing inside the function

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, python-multiprocessing, multiple-instances

I have an A100 GPU which allow me the create multiple instances GPU (MIG) in my system.

I'm trying to execute multiple function in parallel at the same time. When I execute it, it give me error like "`Failed setting context: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: initialization error`". This happen I believe is because each process in the multiprocessing implementation has its own separate memory space and context. Therefore, you need to initialize the CUDA context inside each process separately.

Not sure how should I execute this? The `os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]` doesnt quite to work.  Please if anyone can advice on this.

Below is the example code:

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def cal_1():
    ...
    #Call function with GPU graph mode execution
    
    return 

def cal_2():
    ...
    #Call function with GPU graph mode execution
    
    return 

def cal_3():
    ...
    #Call function with GPU graph mode execution
    
    return 

def cal_4():
    ...
    #Call function with GPU graph mode execution
    
    return 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cal_1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cal_2)
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cal_3)
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cal_4)
      
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
  
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
```

Comment: you can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69115621/cuda-error-not-initialized-on-a100-after-server-reset